# phpmyadmin convert myisam to innodb

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin, innodb

Hey, so I have recently become aware that in order to do foreign key relationships, I need to convert my tables over to innodb. I was wanting to do this in phpmyadmin and found the option for 'storage engine (type)' However my dropdown of options is limited to: `MyISAM`, `MEMORY`, and `MRG_MYISAM`

Would anyone be able to explain why this is?

```
apache 2.0 
phpmyadmin 3.3.10 
mysql 5.0.67
php 5.2.2
```

Thanks!

Comment: In that case I think you need to upgrade you mysql version. I too faced this problem. I just downloaded the latest version of xampp and it worked. I am using MySQL 5.1.41. Try using heidisql, its better than phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InnoDB support has to be enabled on the instance of MySQL you're using.

Try issuing a `SHOW ENGINES` SQL command to see what's available.

Comment: No innodb support :/ Looks like I will have to upgrade my hosting plan :(